# Shelf-Stable Cocktails

Tags: storage-lifetime, syrup, cocktails

I'm a home brewer looking to can up shelf-stable cocktails to share with friends who don't drink beer. I know I'll be using Citric/Malic acid to mimic citrus flavors, but will that be enough to make fruit syrups shelf-stable? Or is there another step to making the syrups stay as well? Hoping to keep these good for 6mo-1yr. Thanks!

Comment: The expert on this, in the US, is Dave Arnold.  He will respond via twitter @CookingIssues.

Comment: You seem to thinking that, if you can make the fruit syrup itself shelf stable, the cocktail with it will also be shelf stable. This is not the case, you can't derive shelf stability from the ingredients' shelf stability, you have to ensure that the exact recipe is shelf stable.

Comment: @rumtscho depends on the ABV of the cocktail, but I don't know the specs.

Comment: What particular cocktails are you looking to make? A bottled Martini is likely to be better than one freshly made and Manhattans aged in oak casks are quite popular. Neither would need anything to make them shelf-stable.